# selected to retrieve all dropdowns which has same selectedindex value

Tags: jquery, selector, html-select

Each row in my table has a dropdown.  the values in the dropdown are "Edit" and "Cancel".  i want to write a jquery selector which will return me all dropdowns with has a selectedvalue as "Edit".  how do i do it?

name of edit control is same for all rows.  am forming edit control dynamically like this.  below code is inside a loop.

```
    $tr.append(
                '<td>' +
                '<select id=\"editOption\">' +
                    '<option value=\"'+pkid+'_select\"></option>' +
                    '<option value=\"'+pkid+'\">Edit</option>' +
                    '<option value=\"'+pkid+'\">Cancel</option>' +
                '</select>' +
                '</td>'
        );
```

As per the suggestion i changed the code to

```
'<td>' + 
    '<select id=\"editOption_'+pkid+'\" class=\"editOption\">' + 
        '<option value=\"-1\"></option>' + 
        '<option value=\"Edit\">Edit</option>' + 
        '<option value=\"Cancel\">Cancel</option>' + 
        '</select>' + 
'</td>'
```

and when I use this:

```
var editedRows = $("table tr select").filter(function() { 
    return $(this).find("option").value == "Edit"; //This should be value, but for your code, its text() 
}); 
console.log(editedRows.length);
```

length is coming as zero.

Comment: Hm.. two things. First, `id`s need to be unique, meaning only one element can have a certain id. I would change the id to include the `pkid` and add a class called "editOption". Second, that's not the right way to use the `value` attribute The values should be something like like "edit" and "cancel".

Comment: as per the suggestion i changed the code to'<td>' +
     '<select id=\"editOption_'+pkid+'\" class=\"editOption\">' +
      '<option value=\"-1\"></option>' +
      '<option value=\"Edit\">Edit</option>' +
      '<option value=\"Cancel\">Cancel</option>' +
     '</select>' +
     '</td>' and when i use this  var editedRows = $("table tr select").filter(function() {
   return $(this).find("option").value == "Edit"; //This should be value, but for your code, its text()
  });
  console.log(editedRows.length); length is coming as zero

Comment: I moved your comment to the question for readability. Instead of `.value` try `.attr('value')`. You might actually be able to do `return $(this).val() == 'Edit';` instead, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `filter` function:

```
var editSelects = $("table tr select").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("option").text() == "Edit"; //This should be value, but for your code, its text()
});
```

Also, per @JasonP comments, your ID's **must** be unique.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine it will alert if selected = Edit

```
var table = document.getElementById("prsnl");  
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); 
for(j = 0 ; rows.length; j++){
var select = rows[j].getElementsByTagName("select");
    for(i = 0; i < select.length; i++){
        alert(select[i].value);
        if(select[i].value.indexOf("Edit") >= 0){
            alert('hi');
        }else{
            alert('fail');
        }
    }
}
```